# How to automatically move an entire row when one cell moves on another sheet

Tags: excel, function, spreadsheet

I have two Excel spreadsheets.  On the first sheet is a list of people's names with other data in the rest of the columns.  In the second sheet, the first column is linked to the names in the first sheet (using "='Sheet1'!B1", etc); however, the rest of the columns in the second sheet are different types of data from the first sheet.  If I want to move a name on the first sheet, this would automatically move the same name on the second sheet, but it won't bring the rest of the data with it.  Is there a way to do this so that data follow the name?

Comment: On sheet1 you can move the cell with the name up. Hold Shift while moving the cell.

Also you could move the whole row up.
But you can't just write the name into another cell.

Comment: Maybe it is best to breake the links?

Comment: This is the expected behavior, if you change the order of Sheet1 it will affect Sheet2, because it refers to the content of a given location. I would have a tab for linked that, then copy the information to another tab in Sheet2 you are going to have additional data, and then to have a way to identify (via formula) when the linked data added a new name so you can add in the copied data tab. So if it is a change in the order, no issue, and if a new name is added to identify it. Via `XLOOKUP`/`XMATCH` for example. Does that work?

Comment: @Basu could you please provide a sample of the data and the expected results?

Comment: Sample: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75115001/automatically-move-an-entire-row-of-reference-cell-when-one-cell-is-moved-or-man

Comment: @Basu: The linked sample does not fit to the problem description.

Comment: When you say *move* what do you mean? if your cell in second sheet is linked with `"='Sheet1'!B1` if you cut the source cell and paste it somewhere else the formula autoupdates. Please add input and expected output

Answer (score 4):

I doubt there is an "canonical answer" because the "problem" is not canonical for Excel. In other words: Excel, which is a spreadsheet application, is not made to solve such problems.

Your assumption "the first column is linked to the names in the first sheet (using "='Sheet1'!B1", etc); " is wrong. The formula `='Sheet1'!B1` does not link to names. The formula result is what value is in `'Sheet1'!B1`. If that value changes, the formula result also changes. That is exactly what you observe and call a "problem".

Linked tables are typical for a relational database system. There one table may have foreign keys to link to another table. See [Foreign key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key). But Excel is not a relational database system.

There is [Power Query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/about-power-query-in-excel-7104fbee-9e62-4cb9-a02e-5bfb1a6c536a) to create a data query from Excel Tables which also is able to have foreign key relations between tables. But this is not really straightforward. So let's have a very simple example:

First create a workbook having two sheets having a data table each.

Example

[image]

Data of Sheet1:

```
Name    Mail                Value1
Name1   name1@example.com   123
Name2   name2@example.com   234
Name3   name3@example.com   234
```

Name of the Table is Data1

[image]

Data of Sheet2:

```
Name    Value2
Name2   2345
Name1   1234
```

Name of the Table is Data2

Now create a Power Query from Table Data1. See [Import from an Excel Table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-from-an-excel-table-8aad8e15-afb7-4adb-b8a5-6ab187ce4f61)

- Select a cell in Table Data1 (is on Sheet1).
- Select **Data > Get & Transform Data > From Table/Range**.
- Excel opens the Power Query Editor with your data displayed in a
  preview pane.
- To return the transformed data to Excel, select Home > Close & Load.

You get an additional sheet having the result of that data query. For me that sheet gets named "Data1".

Now do the same with Table Data2.

- Select a cell in Table Data2 (is on Sheet2).
- Select **Data > Get & Transform Data > From Table/Range**.
- Excel opens the Power Query Editor with your data displayed in a
  preview pane.
- To return the transformed data to Excel, select Home > Close & Load.

You get an additional sheet having the result of that data query. For me that sheet gets named "Data2".

Now select the sheet "Data1" (The sheet which holds the first query result) and edit the query. See [Create, load, or edit a query in Excel (Power Query)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-load-or-edit-a-query-in-excel-power-query-ca69e0f0-3db1-4493-900c-6279bef08df4) - > Edit a query from a worksheet -> To edit a query, locate one previously loaded from the Power Query Editor, select a cell in the data, and then select Query > Edit.

Now merge queries from Data1 with the one from Data2. See [Merge queries (Power Query)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/merge-queries-power-query-fd157620-5470-4c0f-b132-7ca2616d17f9#:%7E:text=You%20can%20perform%20two%20types%20of%20merge%20operation%2C,inline%20merge%3A%20In%20the%20query%20Preview...%20See%20More) -> Perform aMerge operation.

- Select Home > Merge Queries.
- The Merge dialog box appears.
- Select the primary table from the first drop-down list, and then
  select a join column by selecting the column header. This is column
  "Name" in our case.
- Select the related table from the next drop-down list, and then
  select a matching column by selecting the column header. This is
  table "Data2" and column "Name" in our case.
- Select OK.

The result should be an new column "Data2" added to the query "Data1".

Now select the handle at right side of column name "Data2" and mark only "Value2" selected. The coulmn name should change to "Data2.Value2"

To return the transformed data to Excel, select Home > Close & Load.

Result should be the data table on sheet "Data1" cahnged to show the Value2 of Data2 too.

[image]

From now on all changes in Table "Data1" on Sheet1 and in Table "Data2" on Sheet2 will be put together on query result on Sheet "Data1" when you refresh that query.

Disclaimer: This answer is for the linked example in [Automatically move an entire row of reference cell when one cell is moved or manipulated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75115001/automatically-move-an-entire-row-of-reference-cell-when-one-cell-is-moved-or-man).

Answer (score 0):

In Google Sheets, you can use the =QUERY() function to automatically move an entire row when one cell on another sheet changes.

Here is an example of how you can use the =QUERY() function to move an entire row from one sheet to another when a specific cell changes:

```
In the sheet where you want to move the row, create a new column and name it "Status."
In the sheet where the cell that will trigger the move is located, create a new column and name it "Move."
In the "Move" column, use an IF() statement to check if the cell you want to trigger the move is true or false.
    For example: =IF(A1=TRUE,"Move","Stay")
In the sheet where you want to move the row, use the =QUERY() function to select the rows where "Move" is "Move" and "Status" is not "Moved".
    For example: =QUERY(Sheet1!A1:Z,"select * where Move = 'Move' and Status != 'Moved'")
In the sheet where the cell that will trigger the move is located, use the =IF() statement to change the value of the "Status" column to "Moved" when "Move" is "Move".
    For example: =IF(Move="Move","Moved",Status)
Use a script to automatically run the query and update the status every time the cell that triggers the move is changed.
```

Please note that this is an example and you will need to modify the formulas and sheet names to match your specific use case.

hope this helps

Comment: A Google Sheets specific answer doesn't help OP, who is using Excel.

Answer (score 0):

As the question is not really clear about this, there would be another approach if you have the following structure:

Given following data in `Sheet1`:

```
ID  Name    Mail                Value1  Value2
1   Name1   Name1@example.com   123     1234
2   Name2   Name2@example.com   234     2345
3   Name3   Name3@example.com   345     3456
```

[image]

Now `Sheet2` shall only **pull** different data **from** `Sheet1` dependent on Name. Then `Sheet2` could have following formulas filled downwards from row 2:

[image]

`A2`:             `=Sheet1!B2`

`B2:C4`:   `=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$B$1:$E$998,MATCH(Sheet2!B$1,Sheet1!$B$1:$AAA$1,0),FALSE)`

Now you can change data in `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` will always show the correct data for name because of the formulas.

[image]

[image]