# Automatically move an entire row of reference cell when one cell is moved or manipulated

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have more than 1 excel sheets. In Sheet one (master sheet) we have list of colleges. In other sheets, we use reference to those college names. Now we we add a new row in master sheet, all the other sheets also add a new cell in that particular position but do not move the entire row. So what will be the best approach to do it. Through some scripts?

Exact problem description:

[EDIT]
Sheet 1: This is main sheet with college name (Cname) and their joining year (Cval).

| Cname1 | Cval1 |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cname2 | Cval2 |  |  |  |
| Cname3 | Cval3 |  |  |  |
| Cnmae4 | Cval4 |  |  |  |

Sheet 2: This is another sheet which has college names referenced from Sheet 1 (Cname) and one column of any random person name (Dval).

| Cname1 | Dval1 |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cname2 | Dval2 |  |  |  |
| Cname3 | Dval3 |  |  |  |
| Cnmae4 | Dval4 |  |  |  |

Sheet 1: If in Sheet 1, I add a new row:

| Cname1 | Cval1 |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cname2 | Cval2 |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| Cname3 | Cval3 |  |  |  |
| Cnmae4 | Cval4 |  |  |  |

Sheet 2: In Sheet 2, I see a new cell in the row, but the other column (person name) remains as it is.

| Cname1 | Dval1 |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cname2 | Dval2 |  |  |  |
|  | Dval3 |  |  |  |
| Cname3 | Dval4 |  |  |  |
| Cnmae4 |  |  |  |  |

If we were to move all the cells in the row, if the first cell of the row moves, what will be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You can use [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are describing how formula results get misaligned with manually entered data. There is no turn-key solution to work around the issue. It would probably be a good idea to rethink your spreadsheet structure so that data that belongs together is all in the same tab.

Lance has given a thorough [treatment of the row misalignment issue](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/95901649) and how it can be dealt with in some cases.

To answer your question, you should implement a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) that monitors row inserts and deletes, and inserts and deletes rows across other tabs as required. See the [autoInsertAndDeleteRows_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/140954182?msgid=140979349) script for sample code.